# magento 2 Check the status of indexing cron

Tags: magento2

I have magento2 website.I have crontab configured for running the daily crons.How i can verify the indexing cron is running daily.

Also how i can check the current running crons

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To check the configured cron jobs you can use the command `crontab -l` in your terminal and you will see the cron jobs configured and the time they will run.

Based on the cron jobs configured, you can view the status of cron jobs(missed, pending or success) in the `cron_schedule` table.

Connect to your database and run sql query `select * from cron_schedule;` to see the jobs.

In the `cron_schedule` table following fields are present:

`schedule_id`: Atuto-increment id.

`job_code`: code of the cron job. This is defined as job_id="xyz" in any module's etc/crontab.xml file.

`status`: Specifies the current status of this job (misssed/pending/success). 
message: Message of this job.

`created_at`: Specifies the time when entry was made in the table cron_schedule for this job.

`scheduled_at`: Specifies the time when this cron job should run.

`executed_at`: Specifies the time when the execution of this cron job started.

`finished_at`: Specifies the time when execution of this cron job finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch result of cron work in db, table: cron_schedule.

Comment: yes i verified in the table cron_schedule 'indexer_reindex_all_invalid' but it is scheduling for every 2 minutes and completing its execution on the same time (i.e executed_at and finished_at time are same)

Answer (score 0):

try this on SQL

```
select * from cron_schedule WHERE status='running'
```